# Limitar caracters no tesseract portable

Tags: c, ocr, tesseract

Atualmente eu estou utilizando o *tesseract portable* integrado com java para poder identificar alguns caracteres, mas estou enfrentando alguns problemas como:

Alguns campos somente data como : `01/02/2013`

Aparece algo assim: `0Il0S/S013`

Só que não segue nenhum padrão. Alguém faz alguma ideia se tem como criar um dicionário padrão somente para caracteres como `0-9` e `/`?

Lembrando: Eu sei que existe para C, só que a versão portable ainda não encontrei.

Answer (score 1):

Só tenho usado o `tesseract` em Linux, via linha de comando, ou em scripts que mandem
a linha de comando fazer o trabalho...

1) criar um ficheiro de configuração `mydata` com os caracteres válidos:

```
tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789/-
```

2) depois invocar o tesseract como:

```
tesseract f.png zzz   mydata
```

produzindo `zzz.txt` só com digitos e '/' e '-'

Para bons resultados vale a pena investir na qualidade (resolução) da imagem inicial...

Se o âmbito for mais amplos provavelmente será util indicar a língua.

É natural que o interface Java, C, etc tenham funcionalidade para definir
as "whitelists".

Existe ainda a possibilidade de retreinar tesseracts (duvido que se justifique).